# SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: apex, community

i write the code for sending email for batch class . but any limit to sending email viva apex code through , i shared code below

```
public class OpportunityEmailNotification1 implements  Database.Batchable<SObject> {



    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }


    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {

        return Database.getQueryLocator(  [SELECT Id,name,ownerid,owner.email,accountID, Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c,Channel_Partner_Manager__c,
                                            CloseDate, Account.KAM__r.email,  Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email,SAM_ISAM_Email__c,
                                            Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email ,RecordType.Developername
                                            FROM opportunity  where Status__c =:'Open']);



        }



        public static Map<String,    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> createDummyEmail(EmailTemplate templateName, List<opportunity> whatIds){
        //  templateId  must be ID of an Email template
        //  targetObjId must be a Contact Id -- also used in merge fields of template recipient.xxxx
        //  whatId      must be an SObject that is used in the merge fields of the template relatedTo.xxxx
        //  fromId      if non null, use current user, otherwise, use this ID (most likely an org wide no reply id)
        Contact cont = [Select Id, FirstName, Email From Contact Where Email != Null LIMIT 1];


        Map<opportunity,  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> oppEmail = new   Map<opportunity,    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();   
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 

       //system.debug('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'+mapKam);
        for(opportunity whatID :whatIds){
        list<String> ccTo = new list<String>();    

       // system.drbug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'+whatIds.get(whatID));
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
       // user u =[select email from user where id =:whatID.ownerId];      
        msg.setTemplateId(templateName.id );
        msg.setWhatId(whatID.id);
        msg.setTargetObjectId(cont.id);
        if(whatID.RecordType.Developername =='Global_Voice_Record_Type'){
        if(whatID .Account.KAM__r.email!=null)
        ccTo.add(whatID .Account.KAM__r.email);
        if(whatID .Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email!=null)
        ccTo.add(whatID .Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email);
        if(whatID .Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email!=null)
        ccTo.add(whatID .Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email); 
        if(whatID.SAM_ISAM_Email__c!=null)
        ccTO.add(whatID.SAM_ISAM_Email__c);
        } 
        else if( whatID.RecordType.Developername=='Channel_Partner_Opportunity'){
            if(whatID.Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c!=null)
            ccTo.add(whatID.Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c);
            if(whatID.Channel_Partner_Manager__c!=null)
            ccTo.add(whatID.Channel_Partner_Manager__c);
       }
            ccTo.add(whatID.owner.email);  
            system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+ccTo);
            msg.setToAddresses(ccTo);
       // msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{[Select Email From User where name=:'narendra jagwan'].Email});

      msgList.add(msg);  
      oppEmail.put(whatID, msg );   
   }      
        // Send the emails in a transaction, then roll it back
       Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
       Messaging.sendEmail(msgList); // Dummy email send
       Database.rollback(sp); // Email will not send as it is rolled Back
        // Send Actual email  
       system.debug(':::::::::::SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS:::::::::::'+oppEmail);
       List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> EmailList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();     
       String body ='';
       String Subject ='';
       list<string> sender = new list<String>();
       for(opportunity key :oppEmail.keyset()){
          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
          body=oppEmail.get(key).getPlainTextBody();
          Subject =oppEmail.get(key).getSubject();
          sender =oppEmail.get(key).getToAddresses();
          system.debug('*********subject*********'+oppEmail.get(key).getsubject());
          msg1.setSubject(Subject);
          msg1.setPlainTextBody(body);
          msg1.setToAddresses(sender);
          EmailList.add(msg1);
       } 
        try{
        Messaging.sendEmail(EmailList);
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
         {
         throw e; 
        }
        return null ;   
    }  


    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, list<opportunity> records) {
        list <opportunity> opportunityList = new list<opportunity>();

        // id oppID;     
         String ChannelKAMEmail ;
         String ChannelPartnerEmail ;  
         date closerDate;  

         Contact cnt = [select id from Contact  limit 1];
         system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'+cnt );  
         EmailTemplate EmailTemplateName =[SELECT Id  FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'CP - Opportunity Expected Closure date Alert'];

         system.debug('TTTTTTTT'+EmailTemplateName );
         system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAA'+records); 
         for(opportunity  opp :records){
             //oppID= opp.id;
             closerDate= opp.CloseDate ; 
             if(Date.Today() == closerDate-1|| Date.Today() ==closerDate-3 || Date.Today()==closerDate-5){  
                opportunityList.add(opp);    
              }
           }
             createDummyEmail( EmailTemplateName , opportunityList);
         }
     public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // No need to do anything, but this needs to be here

   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is standard exception from Salesforce of Developer and Test Organizations that you cannot send more than 10 emails to external users per 24 hours.

Email sent to internal users doesn't count against this limit.

> In Developer Edition organizations and organizations evaluating
>   Salesforce during a trial period, your organization can send mass
>   email to no more than 10 external email addresses per day. This lower
>   limit does not apply if your organization was created before the
>   Winter '12 release and already had mass email enabled with a higher
>   limit. Additionally, your organization can send single emails to a
>   maximum of 15 email addresses per day.

Comment: hi Ashwan,  but before this error i was send 14 email..

Comment: SettargetobjectID(cont.id) counts as an internal user email. So you can send as many as you want. However, you are ccing to a few other emails as well and I think they count as part of the 10 email limit.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Governor Limits, you can only send 1000 single emails a day (or less, depending on license).

> Using the API or Apex, you can send single emails to a maximum of 1,000 external email addresses per day based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Single emails sent using the Salesforce application don't count toward this limit. There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your organization directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.

I couldn't find any method to get the limit in APEX but you can definitely check the limit as well as remaining emails through Workbench. I have explained in the SFSE link. [Where to find the email api limit?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83137/where-to-find-the-email-api-limit) Hope this helps.